# Python, Pandas datareader and Yahoo Error RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL

Tags: pandas, yahoo-finance, trading, pandas-datareader

I am trying to download historical data from Yahoo using Pandas datareader. This is the code that I normally use:

```
import pandas_datareader as pdr
df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('SPY')
```

However, I started receiving this error today: **RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/SPY/history?period1=1467511200&period2=1625277599&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history**

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Looks like a temporary error at the "Remote" end which Yahoo will fix soon.
Before asking here, check similar issues at https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues?q=RemoteDataError%3A+Unable+to+read+URL

Comment: I also ran into error roughly 2 weeks ago. It is a possibility they have (again) discontinued their API

Comment: @kawingkelvin Oh no! I was enjoying using it. Any good alternatives/workarounds that you know of?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68327968/unable-to-get-stock-data-from-yahoo-with-pandas-datareader/68435757#68435757) already. Since now requires headers, pandas and pandas-datareader must be updated. Other libraries working with pdr might give you issues until gets updated or you modify the part of the code which retreives data.

Have a nice day ;).

```html
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/), run:

```
!pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader

...
Installing collected packages: pandas-datareader
  Attempting uninstall: pandas-datareader
    Found existing installation: pandas-datareader 0.9.0
    Uninstalling pandas-datareader-0.9.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pandas-datareader-0.9.0
Successfully installed pandas-datareader-0.10.0
WARNING: The following packages were previously imported in this runtime:
  [pandas_datareader]
You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions.
```

Go to Runtime -> Restart runtime. Then you can import pandas_datareader and check that it's the right version:

```
import pandas_datareader
pandas_datareader.__version__  # Should show 0.10.0
```