# Unable to get stock data from yahoo with pandas_datareader

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

This is my code:

```
start = '2015-1-1'
end = '2020-12-31'
source = 'yahoo'

google = data.DataReader('GOOG', start=start, end=end, data_source=source).reset_index()
```

I was using this code till last month and it was working properly, after a month I tried this code and now this code is throwing me error:

```
Unable to read URL: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1420065000&period2=1609453799&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history
```

I am not able to figure it out, can you please make me understand, why is this happening?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44045158/python-pandas-datareader-no-longer-works-for-yahoo-finance-changed-url

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yahoo! Finance has changed slightly their structure. **Now requires headers** for the data retreival on the http request. Once done works fine.

For pandas & pandas-datareader which you'll need to **upgrade** them if you use it. (Which has been already sorted). Probably on all other packages using data from yahoo! such backtrader, etc, you'll need either upgrade or add headers on the yahoo! script to retrieve data :).

```html
pip install --upgrade pandas
pip install --upgrade pandas-datareader
```

Have a nice day ;).

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade the pandas_datareader to a version >= 0.10.0 . This bug is fixed in 0.10.0 as per the [release notes](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/releases/tag/v0.10.0).

> Fixed Yahoo readers which now require headers

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! Finance is working fine with pandas without any issue.

**Script:**

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/GOOG/history?period1=1420065000&period2=1609453799&interval=1d&frequency=1d&filter=history'
r = requests.get(link, headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'})
data = pd.read_html(r.text)[0]
df =pd.DataFrame(data)
df=df.iloc[0:100]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
Date            Open    High     Low    Close  AdjClose Volume
Dec 31, 2020    1735.42 1758.93 1735.42 1751.88 1751.88 1011900
Dec 30, 2020    1762.01 1765.09 1725.6  1739.52 1739.52 1306100
Dec 29, 2020    1787.79 1792.44 1756.09 1758.72 1758.72 1299400
Dec 28, 2020    1751.64 1790.73 1746.33 1776.09 1776.09 1393000
Dec 24, 2020    1735    1746    1729.11 1738.85 1738.85 346800
Dec 23, 2020    1728.11 1747.99 1725.04 1732.38 1732.38 1033800
Dec 22, 2020    1734.43 1737.41 1712.57 1723.5  1723.5  936700
Dec 21, 2020    1713.51 1740.85 1699    1739.37 1739.37 1828400
Dec 18, 2020    1754.18 1755.11 1720.22 1731.01 1731.01 4016400
Dec 17, 2020    1768.51 1771.78 1738.66 1747.9  1747.9  1624700
Dec 16, 2020    1772.88 1773    1756.08 1763    1763    1513500
Dec 15, 2020    1764.42 1771.42 1749.95 1767.77 1767.77 1482300
Dec 14, 2020    1775    1797.39 1757.21 1760.06 1760.06 1600200
Dec 11, 2020    1763.06 1784.45 1760    1781.77 1781.77 1220700
Dec 10, 2020    1769.8  1781.31 1740.32 1775.33 1775.33 1362800
Dec 09, 2020    1812.01 1834.27 1767.81 1784.13 1784.13 1507600
Dec 08, 2020    1810.1  1821.9  1796.2  1818.55 1818.55 1096300
Dec 07, 2020    1819    1832.37 1805.78 1819.48 1819.48 1320900
Dec 04, 2020    1824.52 1833.16 1816.99 1827.99 1827.99 1378200
Dec 03, 2020    1824.01 1847.2  1822.65 1826.77 1826.77 1227300
Dec 02, 2020    1798.1  1835.65 1789.47 1827.95 1827.95 1222000
Dec 01, 2020    1774.37 1824.83 1769.37 1798.1  1798.1  1736900
Nov 30, 2020    1781.18 1788.06 1755    1760.74 1760.74 1823800
Nov 27, 2020    1773.09 1804    1772.44 1793.19 1793.19 884900
Nov 25, 2020    1772.89 1778.54 1756.54 1771.43 1771.43 1045800
Nov 24, 2020    1730.5  1771.6  1727.69 1768.88 1768.88 1578000
Nov 23, 2020    1749.6  1753.9  1717.72 1734.86 1734.86 2161600
Nov 20, 2020    1765.21 1774    1741.86 1742.19 1742.19 2313500
Nov 19, 2020    1738.38 1769.59 1737.01 1763.92 1763.92 1249900
Nov 18, 2020    1765.23 1773.47 1746.14 1746.78 1746.78 1173500
Nov 17, 2020    1776.94 1785    1767    1770.15 1770.15 1147100
Nov 16, 2020    1771.7  1799.07 1767.69 1781.38 1781.38 1246800
Nov 13, 2020    1757.63 1781.04 1744.55 1777.02 1777.02 1499900
Nov 12, 2020    1747.63 1768.27 1745.6  1749.84 1749.84 1247500
Nov 11, 2020    1750    1764.22 1747.36 1752.71 1752.71 1264000
Nov 10, 2020    1731.09 1763    1717.3  1740.39 1740.39 2636100
Nov 09, 2020    1790.9  1818.06 1760.02 1763    1763    2268300
Nov 06, 2020    1753.95 1772.43 1740.35 1761.75 1761.75 1660900
Nov 05, 2020    1781    1793.64 1750.51 1763.37 1763.37 2065800
Nov 04, 2020    1710.28 1771.36 1706.03 1749.13 1749.13 3570900
Nov 03, 2020    1631.78 1661.7  1616.62 1650.21 1650.21 1661700
Nov 02, 2020    1628.16 1660.77 1616.03 1626.03 1626.03 2535400
Oct 30, 2020    1672.11 1687    1604.46 1621.01 1621.01 4329100
Oct 29, 2020    1522.36 1593.71 1522.24 1567.24 1567.24 2003100
Oct 28, 2020    1559.74 1561.35 1514.62 1516.62 1516.62 1834000
Oct 27, 2020    1595.67 1606.84 1582.78 1604.26 1604.26 1229000
Oct 26, 2020    1625.01 1638.24 1576.5  1590.45 1590.45 1853300
Oct 23, 2020    1626.07 1642.36 1620.51 1641    1641    1375800
Oct 22, 2020    1593.05 1621.99 1585    1615.33 1615.33 1433600
Oct 21, 2020    1573.33 1618.73 1571.63 1593.31 1593.31 2568300
Oct 20, 2020    1527.05 1577.5  1525.67 1555.93 1555.93 2241700
Oct 19, 2020    1580.46 1588.15 1528    1534.61 1534.61 1607100
Oct 16, 2020    1565.85 1581.13 1563    1573.01 1573.01 1434700
Oct 15, 2020    1547.15 1575.1  1545.03 1559.13 1559.13 1540000
Oct 14, 2020    1578.59 1587.68 1550.53 1568.08 1568.08 1929300
Oct 13, 2020    1583.73 1590    1563.2  1571.68 1571.68 1601000
Oct 12, 2020    1543    1593.86 1532.57 1569.15 1569.15 2482600
Oct 09, 2020    1494.7  1516.52 1489.45 1515.22 1515.22 1435300
Oct 08, 2020    1465.09 1490    1465.09 1485.93 1485.93 1187800
Oct 07, 2020    1464.29 1468.96 1436    1460.29 1460.29 1746200
Oct 06, 2020    1475.58 1486.76 1448.59 1453.44 1453.44 1245400
Oct 05, 2020    1466.21 1488.21 1464.27 1486.02 1486.02 1113300
Oct 02, 2020    1462.03 1483.2  1450.92 1458.42 1458.42 1284100
Oct 01, 2020    1484.27 1499.04 1479.21 1490.09 1490.09 1779500
Sep 30, 2020    1466.8  1489.75 1459.88 1469.6  1469.6  1701600
Sep 29, 2020    1470.39 1476.66 1458.81 1469.33 1469.33 978200
Sep 28, 2020    1474.21 1476.8  1449.3  1464.52 1464.52 2007900
Sep 25, 2020    1432.63 1450    1413.34 1444.96 1444.96 1323000
Sep 24, 2020    1411.03 1443.71 1409.85 1428.29 1428.29 1450200
Sep 23, 2020    1458.78 1460.96 1407.7  1415.21 1415.21 1657400
Sep 22, 2020    1450.09 1469.52 1434.53 1465.46 1465.46 1583200
Sep 21, 2020    1440.06 1448.36 1406.55 1431.16 1431.16 2888800
Sep 18, 2020    1498.01 1503    1437.13 1459.99 1459.99 3103900
Sep 17, 2020    1496    1508.3  1470    1495.53 1495.53 1879800
Sep 16, 2020    1555.54 1562    1519.82 1520.9  1520.9  1311700
Sep 15, 2020    1536    1559.57 1531.83 1541.44 1541.44 1331100
Sep 14, 2020    1539.01 1564    1515.74 1519.28 1519.28 1696600
Sep 11, 2020    1536    1575.2  1497.36 1520.72 1520.72 1597100
Sep 10, 2020    1560.64 1584.08 1525.81 1532.02 1532.02 1618600
Sep 09, 2020    1557.53 1569    1536.05 1556.96 1556.96 1774700
Sep 08, 2020    1533.51 1563.86 1528.01 1532.39 1532.39 2610900
Sep 04, 2020    1624.26 1645.11 1547.61 1591.04 1591.04 2608600
Sep 03, 2020    1709.71 1709.71 1615.06 1641.84 1641.84 3107800
Sep 02, 2020    1673.78 1733.18 1666.33 1728.28 1728.28 2511200
Sep 01, 2020    1636.63 1665.73 1632.22 1660.71 1660.71 1825300
Aug 31, 2020    1647.89 1647.96 1630.31 1634.18 1634.18 1823400
Aug 28, 2020    1633.49 1647.17 1630.75 1644.41 1644.41 1499000
Aug 27, 2020    1653.68 1655    1625.75 1634.33 1634.33 1861600
Aug 26, 2020    1608    1659.22 1603.6  1652.38 1652.38 3993400
Aug 25, 2020    1582.07 1611.62 1582.07 1608.22 1608.22 2247100
Aug 24, 2020    1593.98 1614.17 1580.57 1588.2  1588.2  1409900
Aug 21, 2020    1577.03 1597.72 1568.01 1580.42 1580.42 1446500
Aug 20, 2020    1543.45 1585.87 1538.2  1581.75 1581.75 1706900
Aug 19, 2020    1553.31 1573.68 1543.95 1547.53 1547.53 1660600
Aug 18, 2020    1526.18 1562.47 1523.71 1558.6  1558.6  2027100
Aug 17, 2020    1514.67 1525.61 1507.97 1517.98 1517.98 1378300
Aug 14, 2020    1515.66 1521.9  1502.88 1507.73 1507.73 1354800
Aug 13, 2020    1510.34 1537.25 1508.01 1518.45 1518.45 1455200
Aug 12, 2020    1485.58 1512.39 1485.25 1506.62 1506.62 1437000
Aug 11, 2020    1492.44 1510    1478    1480.32 1480.32 1454400
```

Answer (score -1):

Yahoo finance has decommissioned their API. Try this python [library](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance).